# String Arrays and Pointers

Tags: c++, arrays, string, pointers

```
string *p1 = new string(“hello”);
string *p2 = new string(“world”);
string *p3 = new string(“!!!”);
cout << p1 << ‘ ‘ << p2 << ‘ ‘ << p3 << endl; // print: 0xffa0 0xffb1 0xffd5
string *m[3] = {p1, p2, p3}; // Σημείωση: 32bit αρχιτεκτονική
cout << m; // print: 0x1000
cout << _____m[_____]; // print: 0xffb1 (1 μονάδα)
cout << &m[1]; // print: ___________________ (1 μονάδα)
cout << _____m[_____]; // print: !!! (1 μονάδα)
cout << _____m; // print: hello (1 μονάδα)
cout << &*m[1]; // print: __________________ (1 μονάδα
```

I cant figure out what is happening my outputs are all references not values!
its an old final exercise i must fill each gap to obtain the value that he is telling me.

Comment: As a side note, it would probably be better to use simply `string p1("hello")` etc. in C++.

Comment: Also `m` is not an array of strings. It's an array of string pointers.

Answer (score 2):

```
cout << p1 << ‘ ‘ << p2 << ‘ ‘ << p3 << endl
```

You print out pointers, which are (in essence) addresses of the variables they point to.

```
cout << *p1 << ‘ ‘ << *p2 << ‘ ‘ << *p3 << endl
```

would probably do the trick.

Recommended quick literature: [This](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/pointer)

Answer (score 0):

cout << p1 << ‘ ‘ << p2 << ‘ ‘ << p3 << endl; just typing cout<< p1 will always lead to reference, to get value use dereference operator * like cout<<*p1